# Convert Azure linux OS disk from normal disk (hdd) to standard ssd disk (preview mode)

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, disk

Azure has recently introduced a new type of disks as standard SSD disk (different than the premium SSD). I was wondering if it is possible to change the OS disk type from standard HDD disk to standard SSD disk?

Can I use the same instruction as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/convert-disk-storage) to convert os disk to standard SSD?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the question was more related to Standard HDD to Standard SSD.

```
$diskName = 'yourDiskName'
# resource group that contains the managed disk
$rgName = 'yourResourceGroupName'
# Choose between Standard_LRS and StandardSSD_LRS based on your scenario
$storageType = 'StandardSSD_LRS'

$disk = Get-AzureRmDisk -DiskName $diskName -ResourceGroupName $rgName

# Get parent VM resource
$vmResource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $disk.ManagedBy

# Stop and deallocate the VM before changing the storage type
Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vmResource.ResourceGroupName -Name $vmResource.Name -Force

$vm = Get-AzureRmVM $vmResource.ResourceGroupName -Name $vmResource.ResourceName 

# Update the storage type
$diskUpdateConfig = New-AzureRmDiskUpdateConfig -AccountType $storageType -DiskSizeGB $disk.DiskSizeGB
Update-AzureRmDisk -DiskUpdate $diskUpdateConfig -ResourceGroupName $rgName `
-DiskName $disk.Name

Start-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name
```

Key line in the cmdlets is setting the storage account type.

**$storageType = 'StandardSSD_LRS'**

Article Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/convert-disk-storage#convert-a-managed-disk-from-standard-hdd-to-standard-ssd-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows how to switch all the disks of a VM from standard to premium storage. To use premium managed disks, your VM must use a VM size that supports premium storage. This example also switches to a size that supports premium storage.

```
#resource group that contains the virtual machine
rgName='yourResourceGroup'

#Name of the virtual machine
vmName='yourVM'

#Premium capable size 
#Required only if converting from standard to premium
size='Standard_DS2_v2'

#Choose between Standard_LRS and Premium_LRS based on your scenario
sku='Premium_LRS'

#Deallocate the VM before changing the size of the VM
az vm deallocate --name $vmName --resource-group $rgName

#Change the VM size to a size that supports premium storage 
#Skip this step if converting storage from premium to standard
az vm resize --resource-group $rgName --name $vmName --size $size

#Update the sku of all the data disks 
az vm show -n $vmName -g $rgName --query storageProfile.dataDisks[*].managedDisk -o tsv \
| awk -v sku=$sku '{system("az disk update --sku "sku" --ids "$1)}'

#Update the sku of the OS disk
az vm show -n $vmName -g $rgName --query storageProfile.osDisk.managedDisk -o tsv \
| awk -v sku=$sku '{system("az disk update --sku "sku" --ids "$1)}'

az vm start --name $vmName --resource-group $rgName
```

For more details, refer "[Convert Azure managed disks storage from standard to premium, and vice versa](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/convert-disk-storage)".